# How to keep unspecified variables in handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js

In handlebars, I have this code

```
<p>
    {{A}}
    {{B}}
</p>
```

and then I compile with

```
{"A" : "test"}
```

However the end result is

```
<p>
    test
</p>
```

But what I really want is:

```
<p>
    test
    {{B}}
</p>
```

Since `B` was not defined in the object, I want the variable text to remain. Is there a flag I can pass to the compile or some function to specify this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: You can't, but what you can do is control this with javascript, for example check if B or any other object is defined or not, and then set value to "{{B}}" if it is undefined.

Comment: I solved it, it was right on the homepage. It's `\{{B}}`. To escape, there's other ways to escape too.